# Do we need a tag for Books?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I have found myself using Math.SE for finding books on various subjects.

The way I am doing this is writing the subject followed by the word
book, or by filtering the search results with the reference-request
tag.

For example, just this week I have searched "Probability book" to
get to some books that were recommended in the past.

This method also brings back results like questions from the books
(exercises).

Do we need a tag for books (or book-recommendations) tag?

P.S: I don't know if this feature exist, but I would like to see it [silly me, forgot to ask for the feature!]: Can it be a sub-tag of reference request?

Comment: It already exists, but is a synonym for [reference-request](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request).

Comment: @40votes - I didn't know that. But just the reference-request tags bring results like "Who first/proved/others..."

Comment: I think that "reference-request" is different enough from "book-recommendation" so that having both tags would be useful.

Comment: Does anyone know a history of the synonym? Were there two separate tags [tag:books] and [tag:reference-request] and they were merged? (I did not find any discussion on meta about such merge.) I don't know whether I understand correctly the column named *renames* in the [list of synonyms](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms). Does the number 43 mean that there were 43 questions tagged (books) when the two tags were synonymized?

Comment: As I have been told [on meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190477/what-does-renames-mean-in-the-list-of-tag-synonyms), the number 43 means that since creating the synonyms the tag ([tag:books]) have been used 43 times. (I.e., someone actually typed books in the tags field, which was then automatically changed to ([tag:reference-request]).

Comment: @Belgi As this was your idea, perhaps you should be the person who creates the new tag. (The only thing you have to do is to find a post where the tag is appropriate and add ([tag:book-recommendation]) to the tags.) I would not be surprised if creating this tag could bring you [taxonomist badge](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist), since there probably will be 50 questions of this type soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that total score 10 (13 upvotes/3 downvotes) can be considered as a community consensus for creating the tag. (This is definitely much more voting that we usually see in posts about [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging).)

So I think that the tag [book-recommendation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation) should be created. (In the original post also the name [books](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) was suggested. However, a tag with this name already exists - it is a [synonym for reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/reference-request/synonyms). And the longer name is, in my opinion, clearer.)

Here is my suggestion for tag-excerpt.

> This tag is for questions about recommendation of books for some particular area, topic, problem. Use this tag together with (reference-request) tag.

The reason I suggested that [refence-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refence-request) should be used simultaneously with this tag is that most of the questions asked so far, which could belong under (book-recommendation) are tagged (reference-request). It would be really difficult task to retag them all, so using the (reference-request) could help when searching for such question. (People who are used to look for book recommendations by searching in this tag would not be forced to change their habits.)

Comment: I have followed up on your advice and created the tag.
I have used your description for the tag-excerpt, but it won't be visible until it is reviewed by others.

Comment: Thanks for doing that!

Answer (score 11):

**Yes.** We need a [book-recommendation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation) tag that is not synonymous with [reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request).

Comment: This would, of course, mean retagging a lots of old questions.

Comment: How do we create a tag, and who can edit the corresponding posts ? I don't want to bump 50 questions to the main page and I never created a tag before (should I create a tag myself ?)

Comment: @Belgi You can read about [creating tags](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) in the list of privileges. It requires 300 rep points, so you are well above it.

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to point out that the situation, where we have a separate tag for some special type of books, but questions about [books](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) (and book recommendations) are together with all other [reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request)s, is rather inconsistent.

I am talking about [exercises-and-solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exercises-and-solutions) tag. The tag excerpt says:

> Use this tag for questions asking about "problem books", "exercise books", and their solutions.

I am not sure whether problem books deserve to have a separate tag. But I would definitely prefer it to be a synonym of [books-recommendations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books-recommendations) (which I support) than a synonym of [reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request).

---

As far as possibility of creating [books-recommendations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books-recommendations) is concerned, it might be worth mentioning, that MathOverflow has separate tags ([reference-request](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/reference-request)), ([textbook-recommendation)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/textbook-recommendation)) and ([books](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/books)).

Comment: Apart from mentioning related [tag:exercises-and-solutions] tag, I have posted this answer also to bump this question. (With the hope that some people will see it and upvote/downvote.) I am not sure whether the score 5 (+8/-3) on the other answer is sufficient to be considered community consensus.

Comment: The tag mentioned in this answer [has been blacklisted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16310/rename-exercises-and-solutions-tag-or-completely-remove-it/16381#16381) in the meantime.