# Should we request customized messages for some blacklisted tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-blacklist

Some time ago a new feature was added to SE software, which allows customizing a message shown when a user is trying to add some blacklisted word to a post. See this post on meta.SE: [Allow adding a specific message / guidance to blacklists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217915/allow-adding-a-specific-message-guidance-to-blacklists)

[image: Example of blacklist message]

You might have noticed that a customized message was added when [blacklisting (exercises-and-solutions) tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16310/rename-exercises-and-solutions-tag-or-completely-remove-it/16381#16381).

I do not know what are the requirements on the text used for such messages, the only information I have is from [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16742373#16742373):

> Tim Post said that it should be about a couple of lines long within the pop-up, and that pop-up is exceedingly narrow.

The same thing was discussed when the [algebra tag was blacklisted](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6299/should-the-algebra-tag-be-blacklisted#comment22159_6299), but it was not possible to customize these messages at the time.

Should we request adding some message to some of the [currently blacklisted tags](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16747737#16747737)?

> The current list of blacklisted (and intrinsic) tags is: [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math), [mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics), [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof), [equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equation), [equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equations), [algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra), [graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph), [graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs), [untagged](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged), [gm.general-mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gm.general-mathematics), [exercises-and-solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exercises-and-solutions), [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework).

I should thank to Arthur Fischer, who provided me with the information I quoted above, when we briefly discussed this [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/custom-messages-for-blacklisted-tags).

Comment: Speaking of this I have noticed that when I try to enter homework as one of the tags, I receive the warning saying that this tag is not allowed and containing the following text: *Please do not use the 'homework' tag, it's currently deprecated and will be removed entirely within the week. For more information, please see [the related meta discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16425/fate-of-the-homework-tag-the-community-voted-now-what).* I think that it should be somehow rephrased, or at least the sentence that it *will be removed entirely within the week* should be omitted.

Comment: For example it might be good adding some explanation for (algebra) (saying that (abstract-algebra) and (algebra-precalculus) should be used) or for graph/graphs (mentioning (graph-theory) and (graphing-functions)).

Answer (score 5):

As it might by confusing to new users, I think some kind of explanation why algebra tag is blacklisted could be useful.

I think that in addition to the default message

> The 'algebra' tag is not allowed.

we might add something like:

> Choose some other tags, for example, [abstract-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/abstract-algebra/info) or [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/algebra-precalculus/info).

Please upvote/downvote this post to show whether you agree with this. Feel free to suggest better wording in comments (or edit this answer).

Comment: This has been done.

Answer (score 5):

As it might by confusing to new users, I think some kind of explanation why the tags graph and graphs are blacklisted could be useful.

I think that in addition to the default messages "The 'graph' tag is not allowed" and "The 'graphs" tag is not allowed"

we might add something like:

> Choose some other tags, for example, [graph-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/graph-theory/info) or [graphing-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/graphing-functions/info).

Please upvote/downvote this post to show whether you agree with this. Feel free to suggest better wording in comments (or edit this answer).

Comment: This has been done.