# Do we need/want an overarching books question?

Tags: discussion

Echoing the [Physics Meta question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5307/do-we-need-want-an-overarching-books-question) on this topic, does Math.SE have the will and use case for building a community list of books? [Such a list has successfully been curated on the Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations), and I would honestly appreciate this for mathematics. The [Math.SE community has discussed the need for tags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10393/do-we-need-a-tag-for-books), and [there does exist a `book-recommendation` tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation). One can also see that [there are numerous questions requesting for book recommendations on a variety of subjects](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=book+recommendations). These observations suggest to me that there might be a want and use case, but I would appreciate the perspectives of others that have ideas about this option.

> Do we need/want an overarching books question?

Answer (score 1):

No, for the same reason the question has been closed on Physics.SE:

*"As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."*

Like with all questions, book-recommendation answers must be supported by facts, references, etc. There are many answers limited to "I like this book". A curated list would likely offer no way to check why precisely a book has been chosen. Something that could be done in a specific case, with answers adapted to the level and aspirations of the asker.

A curated list represents the opinion of its author(s). It's good for a blog.

---

**Edit:** I may have misunderstood the question. The curated list you point to is a list of links to Physics.SE questions. If I understand correctly now, book-recommendation questions with good answers were selected. Such a list **is** useful.

Comment: That may be due to the post intentionally being edit-only: *This question's answers are a community effort. Edit existing answers to improve this post. It is not currently accepting new answers or interactions.*

Comment: An edit-only approach probably removes needless discussions, and possibly improves the signal-to-noise-ratio of the contributed edits.

Comment: Ah! You're right, I did not add the fact that the list links to existing recommendations with good answers. Thank you for pointing that out.